# Jest - Mock function that is not being exported

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a file that exports one function that relies on a private one:

```
function __a(filePath, someFunction){
  // do some file request
  someFunction(filePath)
}

function b(filePath){
  __a(filePath, require)
}

module.exports = {
  b: b
}
```

And I'd like to test that the private function `__a` `toHaveBeenCalledWith` some parameters so `__a` does not actually try and fetch some file I can not assure exists.

I understand the concept that when I'm importing `b` I am getting a reference to the function and `__a` just lives within the scope of it, and I can't have access to it so using stuff like:

```
import appResources from './index';
// ... test
jest.spyOn(applicationResources, '__a').mockImplementationOnce(myParams);
```

How can I avoid `__a` excecution here and make sure it's been called?

Comment: If you're testing `b`, you shouldn't be mocking out other parts of its module. If you're testing something that *uses* `b`, it shouldn't know about `__a` at all.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to mock or spy on existing function that isn't used as a method.

`__a` and `b` should either reside in different modules, or `a` should be used as a method within same module. For CommonJS modules there's existing `exports` object that can be used:

```
exports.__a = function __a(filePath, someFunction){
  // do some file request
  someFunction(filePath)
}

exports.b = function b(filePath){
  exports.__a(filePath, require)
}
```

Notice that `module.exports` isn't replaced, otherwise it won't be possible to refer it as `exports`.